# Mathematica how to efficiently find the minimum value using an ordering function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have the following list of pairs of data:

```
pairs = {{3, "John"}, {1, "Bob"}, {2, "Jane"}, {1, "Beth"}};
```

I would like to find the pair of data with the minimum first value.  In the example above the pair I am looking for is: `{1, "Bob"}` or `{1, "Beth"}`, but not both of them.

I can use `Sort[pairs, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &][[1]]` to accomplish this. However, since even the fastest sorts having a big O > O(n), it leads me to think there has to be a more efficient way to do this.

The following gives me the correct answer:

```
minPair = pairs[[1]];
Map[Function[x, If[x[[1]] < minPair[[1]], minPair = x]], pairs];
minPair;
```

but, it is slower than using `Sort` above. I know, my Mathematica-fu is just not there yet, hence my question.

### Timings

```
SetAttributes[TimingDo, HoldRest];
TimingDo[note_String, func_] := 
  results = 
   Append[results, {note , func, Timing[Do[func, {iterations}]][[1]]}];

pairs = {{3, "John"}, {1, "Bob "}, {2, "Jane"}, {1, "Beth"}};
results = {};
iterations = 10000;

TimingDo[ "mmorris[Sort]:               ",
  Sort[pairs, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &][[1]]];

TimingDo["mmorris[Map]:                ",
  minPair = pairs[[1]];
  Map[Function[x, If[x[[1]] < minPair[[1]], minPair = x;]], pairs];
  minPair];

TimingDo["mmorris[Map2]:               ",
  minPair = pairs[[1]];
  minValue = minPair[[1]];
  Map[Function[x, 
    If[x[[1]] < minValue, minPair = x; minValue = minPair[[1]];]], 
   pairs];
  minPair];

TimingDo["Mike Honeychurch[Position]:  ",
  pairs[[Position[pairs, Min[pairs[[All, 1]]]][[1, 1]]]]];

TimingDo["Mike Honeychurch[Ordering]:  ",
  pairs[[First@Ordering[pairs[[All, 1]]]]]];

TimingDo["Mike Honeychurch[Ordering']: ",
  pairs[[First@Ordering[pairs[[All, 1]], 1]]]];

TimingDo["Mike Honeychurch[SortBy]:    ",
  SortBy[pairs, First][[1]]];

cf = Compile[{{in, _Integer, 1}}, Block[{x, pos}, x = Part[in, 1];
    pos = 0;
    Do[If[Part[in, i] < x, x = Part[in, i];
       pos = i;];, {i, Length[in]}];
    pos]];

TimingDo["ruebenko[Compile]:           ",
  {p1, p2} = Developer`ToPackedArray /@ Transpose[pairs];
  pairs[[cf[p1]]]];

TimingDo[ "ruebenko[Ordering]:          ",
  {p1, p2} = Developer`ToPackedArray /@ Transpose[pairs];
  pairs[[Ordering[p1][[1]]]]];

TimingDo["TomD[Select]:                ",
  Select[pairs, #[[1]] == Min[pairs[[All, 1]]] &, 1][[1]]];

TimingDo["TomD[Function]:              ",
  (Function[xx, Select[xx, #[[1]] == Min[xx[[All, 1]]] &, 1]]@
     pairs)[[1]]];

Map[Print, Sort[results, #1[[3]] < #2[[3]] &]];
```

### Results (List size of 4)

`pairs = {{3, "John"}, {1, "Bob "}, {2, "Jane"}, {1, "Beth"}};`

```
{Mike Honeychurch[Ordering']: ,{1,Bob },0.01381}

{Mike Honeychurch[Ordering]:  ,{1,Bob },0.016171}

{Mike Honeychurch[SortBy]:    ,{1,Beth},0.036649}

{TomD[Select]:                ,{1,Bob },0.042448}

{Mike Honeychurch[Position]:  ,{1,Bob },0.042909}

{ruebenko[Ordering]:          ,{1,Bob },0.048088}

{ruebenko[Compile]:           ,{1,Bob },0.050277}

{TomD[Function]:              ,{1,Bob },0.054296}

{mmorris[Sort]:               ,{1,Beth},0.06838}

{mmorris[Map2]:               ,{1,Bob },0.117905}

{mmorris[Map]:                ,{1,Bob },0.119051}
```

### Results (List size of 1000)

`pairs = RandomInteger[1000, {1000, 2}];`

```
{Mike Honeychurch[Ordering']: ,{0,217},0.236041}

{ruebenko[Compile]:           ,{0,217},0.416627}

{ruebenko[Ordering]:          ,{0,217},0.675427}

{Mike Honeychurch[Ordering]:  ,{0,217},0.771243}

{Mike Honeychurch[SortBy]:    ,{0,217},2.68054}

{Mike Honeychurch[Position]:  ,{0,217},2.70455}

{mmorris[Map2]:               ,{0,217},26.7715}

{mmorris[Map]:                ,{0,217},29.8413}

{mmorris[Sort]:               ,{0,217},98.1023}

{TomD[Function]:              ,{0,217},115.968}

{TomD[Select]:                ,{0,217},116.78}
```

Comment: What is the length of your real life lists?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Real life list size for this application is any where between 1 (yes 1) and 20 items in the list.

Comment: Ordering will probably be your fastest method I think. If the list length is only up to ~20 then no packing needed. There is overhead in packing lists so for small lists it will make things slower. Rule of thumb I use is length of ~250.

Comment: @mmorris, you timings are not really useful, because the `pairs` list you use is so short.  If you try the timings with a much longer list you will get different results.  (Omit the first method or it will never finish.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The timing information is relevant to the specific question I asked.  Which was clarified in comment #2.  However, I do not disagree with you that the timing results will vary depending up the context of the problem.  Hence why I included the source code for all the answers submitted so the context can be tweaked as the situation dictates.  This way people can find the solution that best fits their context.

Comment: I am sorry, I missed that comment.  I assumed the actual set was longer.

Comment: I added result for list of length of 1000

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find all the minimums like this:

```
pos = Position[pairs, Min[pairs[[All, 1]]]]

pairs[[pos[[All, 1]]]]
```

If you only want one of them then

```
pos = Position[pairs, Min[pairs[[All, 1]]]][[1, 1]]

pairs[[pos]]
```

On my machine this is faster than the methods listed in your question and I would expect it to be much faster for larger lists.

**Edit**

Actually this is faster still -- for your small list.

```
pos = First@Ordering[pairs[[All, 1]]];
pairs[[pos]]
```

Best to test all these on your real life lists for timings. (Note also that `SortBy[pairs,First]` is faster than `Sort`)

Comment: Thanks! See my question for the results.

Comment: While dissecting your answer ... I think I found an improvement: `pairs[[First@Ordering[pairs[[All, 1]], 1]]]`

Comment: I just split it, and the others, into 2 lines for clarity

Comment: Not the split, the second argument to Ordering that limits it to only n results, in this case I only need 1.

Comment: ok. sorry I missed that in your comment. Yes that seems about 5-10% faster.

Comment: Mike, note that `SortBy[pairs, {First}]` can be significantly faster than `SortBy[pairs, First]` because it does not do tie-breaking.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by tie-breaking? Do you mean an additional sort of the second and/or subsequent terms in a row when the first terms are the same? If so that is handy to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
pairs = {{3, "John"}, {1, "Bob"}, {2, "Jane"}, {1, "Beth"}};
{p1, p2} = Developer`ToPackedArray /@ Transpose[pairs]

cf = Compile[{{in, _Integer, 1}}, Block[{x, pos},
   x = Part[in, 1];
   pos = 0;
   Do[
    If[Part[in, i] < x,
      x = Part[in, i];
      pos = i;
      ];
    , {i, Length[in]}];
   pos
   ]]


pairs[[cf[p1]]]
```

The best you can expect is O(n) since, you have to walk the list once, to find the min value.

Here is a second idea:

```
pairs = {{3, "John"}, {1, "Bob"}, {2, "Jane"}, {1, "Beth"}};
{p1, p2} = Developer`ToPackedArray /@ Transpose[pairs]
ord = Ordering[p1]
pairs[[ord[[1]]]]
```

Comment: Thanks! See my question for the results.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select[pairs, #[[1]] == Min[pairs[[All, 1]]] &, 1]
```

gives

```
{{1, "Bob"}}
```

or, alternatively:

```
Function[xx, Select[xx, #[[1]] == Min[xx[[All, 1]]] &, 1]]@pairs
```

I am asking `Select` to return just the first element for which the select criterion is true (hence the third argument)

**Edit**

Another possibility:

```
min = Min[pairs[[All, 1]]];
pairs /. {___, {min, x_}, ___} :> {min, x}
```

Comment: Thanks! See my question for the results.